# Unable to post reply to _some_ comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Sometimes, when I post a reply to a comment through the graph API on a FB page (replies are enabled in the page parameters), I get generic FB "transient" errors which are not transient:

```
{u'error': {u'code': 2, u'message': u'An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.', u'is_transient': True, u'type': u'OAuthException'}}
```

A typical example is: https://www.facebook.com/VoyagesSncf.com/posts/377070219021428 where I cannot even post replies myself using the FB web interface.

I wonder if someone would know what could cause this specific FB discussion to behave this way and what I could do to detect programmatically that I need to give up on posting a reply and s

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a facebook api's bug, reported here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/281179468741734/

I've got the same problem while creating a new (even unpublished) post. But it is transient indeed, but it may took a few ours, when facebook will behave as expected.

I'm afraid, there is no workaround for this issue for now.